# Грамматические основы спп:

Tags: спп, основа

Телефонисты тут же мстительно вырубили важного начальника, который продолжал греметь в трубку отключенного телефона.

1 - телефонисты вырубили;

2 - продолжал греметь.

А подлежащего здесь нет? Или *который* - это подлежащее?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Телефонисты** тут же мстительно **вырубили** важного начальника, **который** **продолжал греметь** в трубку отключенного телефона.

Который - союзное слово в роли подлежащего, продолжал греметь - составное глагольное сказуемое, фазовый вспомогательный глагол "продолжал".